# CSS; is there a way not to apply css on certain div and its children

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen jquery drop down on my web page, the dropdown list control is inside the div.

```
<div >
<asp:DropDownList  ID="selUser" runat="server" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select a Distributor"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Eaxmple: http://jsfiddle.net/2bhrLxoa/

After rending, plugin drop down values are in div and plugin css is inheriting custom css class settings for div.

```
<div>
    <select id="selUser" class="chosen-select" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
        <option value="0">Select User</option>
        <option value="1">Yogesh singh - 12087</option>
        <option value="2">Sonarika Bhadoria - 120875</option>
        <option value="3">Anil Singh - 1208766</option>
        <option value="4">Vishal Sahu - 12087765</option>
        <option value="5">Mayank Patidar - 120870</option>
        <option value="6">Vijay Mourya - 12087675</option>
        <option value="7">Rakesh sahu - 120876433</option>
    </select>
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" title="" id="selUser_chosen" style="width: 80%;">
        <a class="chosen-single">
            <span>Select User</span>
            <div>
                <b></b>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="chosen-drop">
            <div class="chosen-search">
                <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <ul class="chosen-results">
                    <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Select User</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Yogesh singh - 12087</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Sonarika Bhadoria - 120875</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Anil Singh - 1208766</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">Vishal Sahu - 12087765</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">Mayank Patidar - 120870</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6">Vijay Mourya - 12087675</li>
                    <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="7">Rakesh sahu - 120876433</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This div is inheriting padding from custom class**

```
    <div class="chosen-drop">
```

Web page is using the custom css file where div has 4px padding for the entire page and i can't change that.

```
div {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Is there a way Not to inherit div css settings ?

**View when inherting 4px padding;**
[image]

**View without 4px padding;**
[image]

Comment: The simple answer is to add in one of your css files: `div.chosen-container,
div.chosen-container div { padding: 0; }` like http://jsfiddle.net/g83Ljzsn/

Comment: Thanks its working :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reset the padding on `.chosen-drop` to the [initial](http://.chosen-drop%20div), and [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) it on it's children, so they can still inherit from their parents.

**Node:** you should load this CSS before the plugin's CSS, so the plugin can override it.

```css
div {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.chosen-drop {
  padding: initial;
}

.chosen-drop div {
  padding: unset;
}
```

```html
<div>
  outside chosen-drop
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    chosen-drop
    <div>inside chosen-drop</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case this works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51w0qbcv/)):

```
.chosen-container {
  padding: initial;
}

.chosen-container div {
  padding: unset;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/2bhrLxoa/

Comment: doesn't work in IE11. This is now working div.chosen-container, div.chosen-container div { padding: 0; }